# Кроссбраузерность webkit и moz.

Tags: кроссбраузерность

В Опере и Хроме:

[image: хром]

Мозила:

[image]

Речь о уголке слова мотозапчасти. Получается визуальная разница значения top в 2пкс... Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Comment: @mi4i, может, это и круто, но лучше изначально делать как надо, чтобы потом не спотыкаться о глупости такие.

Comment: какие такие? не понял...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

может, hack for firefox поможет:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .selector {
     top: 4px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[[@mi4i](/users/20430/mi4i)](/users/20430/mi4i), скрины, конечно же, это хорошо, но еще лучше, если бы код показали, а в идеале - и примерчик в песочнице. Пока могу чисто интуитивно предложить, чтобы для шапки задать свойство **box-sizing** со значением **border-box**

```
header_selector {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```